# Powershell FolderBrowserDialog behaving differently from shell to ise

Tags: powershell, folderbrowserdialog

When I run the below code in Powershell ISE everything runs fine, but when I run it from Powershell Shell I get a lot of errors about icons.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms") |Out-Null

$foldername = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog 
$foldername.Description = "Select a folder"
$foldername.rootfolder = "MyComputer"
$foldername.SelectedPath = $initialDirectory

if($foldername.ShowDialog() -eq "OK")
{
    $folder += $foldername.SelectedPath
}

$folder
```

Example of Errors:

```
2021-10-19 15:44:43,174 ERROR - 4600 Unable to get icon for location (The operation completed successfully.): C:\Users\adalton\Pictures\Camera Roll
2021-10-19 15:44:43,176 ERROR - 4600 Unable to get icon for location (The operation completed successfully.): C:\Users\adalton\Pictures\Saved Pictures
C:\Users\adalton\Pictures\Saved Pictures
```

Comment: How is the file encoded? And what Version of powershell do you use? Powershell V5 and V7 have some incompatibilities with the encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adalton,

Note that the ISE has things automatically loaded that the CMD version does not and must be loaded by the programmer. The modified code below (read the comments in the code) works on both the ISE and CMD versions of PowerShell 5.1.19041.1237

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.windows.forms

$Folder = @()  #Set up blank array so += works!

$TermMsg = {
  [Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($Message,
                                   "$Title",
  [Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK ,
  [Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Information) | Out-Null}

If ($host.Name -eq 'ConsoleHost' -or
    $host.Name -eq 'Visual Studio Code Host') {

  try{  <#+------------------------------------------------+
          | Check that the proper assemblies are loaded    |
          | Required for PS Console and Visual Code, while |
          | only Systems.Windows.Forms needed for PSISE!   |
          +------------------------------------------------+
        #>
    $ATArgs = @{AssemblyName = "PresentationCore",
                               "PresentationFramework",
                               "WindowsBase"
                ErrorAction = 'Stop'}
    Add-Type @ATArgs
  }
  catch {
    $Title   = "Program Terminated:"
    $Message =
        "Failed to load Windows Presentation Framework" +
        " and/or other assemblies required for this program!"
     & $TermMsg
    Exit
  }

} #End If ($host.Name...

$foldername = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog 
$foldername.Description = "Select a folder"

#Root Folder is restricted see here: 
#https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=net-5.0
$foldername.rootfolder = [System.Environment+SpecialFolder]'MyComputer'

#$foldername.SelectedPath = $initialDirectory

if($foldername.ShowDialog() -eq "OK")
{
    $folder += $foldername.SelectedPath
}

$folder
```